# CSS, cant figure out how to change this element in a theme

Tags: html, css

so I have this HTML template in which I would like to change something, but I cannot figure out how. What I need to do is make it so the top carousel thing is smaller, and does not take up the whole page, I have tried going into the css file, but it does not seem to be working. I tried to edit the ID of the carousel and put the height to 50 percent. How can I do this, thanks!

Here is a link to the template live: http://sitediscount.ru/parallaxer_new/
The CSS file is located atL http://sitediscount.ru/parallaxer_new/assets/css/style.css

Here is the default CSS code for the carousel:

```
    /* ################ Carousel sliders section#####################  */

/******* TOP SLIDER
**************/

.slider_top {
    padding-top:160px;
}



.slider_top .carousel-control {
position: absolute;
top: 250px;

}

.slider_top .carousel-control {
position: absolute;
top: 340px;
}
.slider_top .btn-control {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
overflow: visible;
cursor: pointer;
outline: 0;
border: 0;
background: #e93f33;
padding: 18px 8px;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 200;
color: #fff;
border: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1), 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.25), 8px 8px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1), 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.25), 8px 8px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1), 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.25),8px 8px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

}

.slider_top .carousel-control.left{
    left:0px;
}

.slider_top .carousel-control.right{
    right:0px;
}

.slider_top .hero-unit {
    padding-top:30px !important;
}

/**********************SECTION SLIDER ***********************/
#slider-section {
    background:url( ../img/blogbg.png) repeat;
}

#slider-section .page-header h3{
    background:url( ../img/blogbg.png) repeat;
}

#carousel_vertical_slide.carousel, #carousel_vertical_slide_2.carousel, #carousel_horizontal_slide.carousel, #carousel_horizontal_slide_2.carousel{
    min-height:400px;
    margin:40px 0px;
}

.span6 #carousel_fade.carousel, .span6 #carousel_fade_2.carousel{
    min-height:280px;
    height:300px;
    margin:40px 0px;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control{
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    -khtml-opacity:0;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.carousel-fade:hover .carousel-control{
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    -khtml-opacity:1;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#carousel_fade.carousel .carousel-control.right, #carousel_fade_2.carousel .carousel-control.right{
    right:0px;
}

#carousel_fade.carousel .carousel-control.left, #carousel_fade_2.carousel .carousel-control.left{
    left:0px;
}
.carousel-control.btn-control {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
}

.carousel-inner .item img {
    display: inline-block !important;
}

.carousel-inner .item {
    text-align: center !important;
}

@media (max-width: 570px) {
    .carousel-control.left {
        left: 0;
    }
    .carousel-control.right {
        right: 0;
    }
}

.carousel-control {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel.horizontal .next {
    left: 100%;
}

.carousel.horizontal .prev {
    left: -100%;
}

.carousel.horizontal .active.left {
    left: 100%;
}

.carousel.horizontal .active.right {
    left: -100%;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .item {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    opacity:0;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .active.item {
    opacity:1;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .active.left,
.carousel.carousel-fade .active.right {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .next,
.carousel.carousel-fade .prev {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
    z-index: 3;
}

.vertical .carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .item {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
     -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
      -ms-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
       -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
          transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
}

.carousel.vertical .active {
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .next {
  top: 400px;
}

.carousel.vertical .prev {
  top: -400px;
}

.carousel.vertical .next.left,
.carousel.vertical .prev.right {
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .active.left {
  top: -400px;
}

.carousel.vertical .active.right {
  top: 400px;
}

.carousel.vertical .item {
    left: 0;
}
.carousel .inactive {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: -1;
}

.carousel .inactive.active {
    position: relative !important;
    z-index: 0;

}

.btn-control {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
overflow: visible;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 5px;
margin-top: 8px;
cursor: pointer;
outline: 0;
border: 0;
background-color: #fff;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#eee);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#eee);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fff),to(#eee));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#eee);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#eee);
background-image: linear-gradient(top,#fff,#eee);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff',endColorstr='#eeeeee',GradientType=0);
-webkit-background-clip: padding;
-moz-background-clip: padding;
background-clip: padding;
zoom: 1;
z-index: 1;
font-family: "Segoe UI",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 14px;
color: #333;
min-width: 42px;
text-shadow: #fff 0 1px 0;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: inherit;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1), 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.25), 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1), 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.25), 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1), 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.25),4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.btn-control:hover, .btn-control:focus, .btn-control:active, .btn-control.active {
color: #333;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #dcdcdc;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#dcdcdc,#dcdcdc);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#dcdcdc,#dcdcdc);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#dcdcdc),to(#dcdcdc));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#dcdcdc,#dcdcdc);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#dcdcdc,#dcdcdc);
background-image: linear-gradient(top,#dcdcdc,#dcdcdc);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dcdcdc',endColorstr='#dcdcdc',GradientType=0);
z-index: 100;
outline: 0;
}

.btn-control i{
    font-size:18px;
}
```

Here is the HTML code of the carousel:

```
<div id="carousel_horizontal_slide_2" class="carousel slide slider_top">
                <div class="carousel-inner">

                    <!--########## item #############-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="hero-unit text-center">
                        <h1 class="">

                        <span class="active">PARALLAXER </span></h1>
                        <!-- !! DEL Class="active" when used static animated h1 script -->
                                <h2 class="text-center">
                                    Start &amp; grow faster with PARALLAXER
                                </h2>
                            </div>


                    </div>
                    <!--############/item###########-->

                    <!--########## item #############-->
                    <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/browserthree.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <!--############/item###########-->

                    <!--########## item #############-->
                    <div class="item active">
                    <img src="images/responsiveshwcase.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <!--############/item###########-->



                </div>

                <a class="carousel-control left btn-control " href="#carousel_horizontal_slide_2" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa-icon-double-angle-left main-color"></i></a>
                <a class="carousel-control right btn-control btn-action" href="#carousel_horizontal_slide_2" data-slide="next"><i class="fa-icon-double-angle-right main-color"></i></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the JavaScript in the page is setting the height of the `<header>`. You can change whatever you want in the CSS, but when the JavaScript is run it will set the height of the header to the size of the window, making it so it keeps taking up the whole screen.

You can determine this by going into the developer console/panel/whatever in a browser and manually setting the height of the header element. It will change. But as soon as you re-size the page a bit it will return to taking up the full size of the screen it will have the CSS attribute `height` set to the height of the window.

To change it, you'll have to go into the JS files, find the offending code, and either put in an exception for the header or remove that functionality and pray that the website works without it. You could also always disable JavaScript entirely, but you'll probably have to make some changes to compensate for it.

Comment: Do you know which JS file is doing this?http://www.sitediscount.ru/parallaxer_new/assets/js/ they are all there.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not going to be very easy. I think what they're doing is a generic thing that performs this over a set of elements that happens to contain the header. They never specify changing the header itself (there is never a jquery selector for anything containing 'head' which is contained in all of the header's classes, id, and element name). You'll have to step through the JS and find out which one OR find their main javascript and read through it.

Comment: I have all the files open right now, and I can search all of them at once, what would you recommend searching?

Comment: I'm *guessing* that it will be in [nicescroll.js](http://www.sitediscount.ru/parallaxer_new/assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.js) but I don't know about that one.